# How do I push vertices?

Tags: geometry

I have create a model that looks like this:

[image]

I would like to move some vertices inwards.

I thought this action was called "Pushing", but I didn't find any tutorial for this.

Here is what I want to do and what my actual results are.

I have selected the vertices which I want to push / crunch, and then I used scaling. Because because scaling uses the center of the selected vertices as the center for scaling, it doesn't work as I expected.

What would be a good / the right way to do what I need to do?

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try using proportional editing (O)

Comment: When I active it, and I scale as usual, then my entire model (and not only the selected vertices) are scaled. Is that a bug perhaps?

Comment: You have to select the bottom-most edge(s) only and scroll the mousewheel to shrink the circle of influence as small as still works for you (it may not - it might still get too many vertices). Also, don't try to scale the object, instead, grab the bottom edges and move them "up".

Comment: If I select the edges and use the mouse wheel, it just scrolls my view. The white circle does not change.

Comment: You have to scroll the mousewheel after initiating the move operation (G).

Comment: Yes, I did that. Here is a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dCGx2F0F3_k

Comment: As soon as I type "G", it moves the entire model around even though only a few vertices are selected. And using the mouse wheel has no effect. I have uploaded my blend file to this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here's a better approach for your project - Select the whole bottom "block" like in your image, but make sure one of the top edges is selected last (active). Next,  change the *Transform Pivot Point* to "active element".

[image: Scale]

Now scale on the Y-axis:

[image: Scale2]

Comment: How do I get the zoom correct as you proposed? When I move up the wheel up 20 times, my view is way too close to the model. At this view, I can not select anything.

Comment: I changed my answer to a better method for your project.

Comment: How do I make it so that the 1 edge is selected? When I click it, I lose the selection of the other vertices.

Comment: Thank you, I got it now: I have to first select that one vertex to make it the active one, and then do the selection of the others using "b".